# Why is CalendarView showing day 17 of october twice?

Tags: android, calendarview

i am using a simple CalendarView in my android app:

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:showWeekNumber="false"
    android:shownWeekCount="5"/>
```

Why is it showing day 17 twice?

[image]

When i click on day 18, it selects day 17, day 19 selects day 18. It keeps getting the wrong day from 17 to 23 (there's no day 24). Day 25 it gets back to normal.
Something i noticed that may be related (or not) from day 17 to 18 here starts the daylight saving time. Im using GMT -2 Brasilia Time Zone.
Tested on Android 5.0.2 and 4.1.1 (both same problem)

Comment: Change the language of mobile to English and try.

Comment: still same problem after changing to english.

Comment: I tried this but its work fine in my app ... please post your java code also

Comment: If i change to another timezone it works fine. When i get back to my current timezone GMT -2 Brasilia, the problem comes back.

Comment: This could be a phone bug. Have you tried same app on a different phone/emulator?

Comment: Tested on Phone Sony xperia e1604 and Tablet LG-V400